# Strange controls animation after transitionWithView

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiview, uiviewanimation

I am trying to transition from one view to another.
The final view I'm transitioning to is a XIB with a couple buttons and a title bar.
My problem is that after the transition, the buttons get displayed on the very top left of the window for a fraction of a second, and eventually "drag" to their expected coordinates.  Everything is perfectly usable and functional, but the transition looks a little funny.
Any idea what could cause this?

Here is my code snipet:

```
Homepage *hp = [[Homepage alloc] init];
hp.data = self.data;

[UIView transitionWithView:self.view duration:0.5
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlDown
                animations:^ { [self.view addSubview:hp.view]; }
                completion:nil];
[hp DisplayThumbnails];
[hp release];
```

Comment: Try adding the subview while it's hidden prior to the animation, then setting it to visible within the animation block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to provide the code snippet that I've used to resolve this problem using Jacob's recommendation in case someone else runs into this.  Here it is:

```
Homepage *hp = [[Homepage alloc] init];
hp.data = self.data;
[hp.view setHidden:YES];

[self.view addSubview:hp.view];
[UIView transitionWithView:self.view duration:0.5
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlDown
                animations:^ { [hp.view setHidden:NO];}
                completion:nil];
[hp DisplayThumbnails];
```